# Where should I begin with this database design?

Tags: sql, database-design, normalization

I have 5 tables all unnormalised and I need to create an ER model, a logical model, normalise the data and also a bunch of queries.

Where would you begin? Would you normalise the data first? Create the ER model and the relationships?

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: Yes, just asking for tips not answers!

Comment: If it is homework, you should add the homework tag, so people know it is.

Comment: Oh right just done that now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to start data modelling: top-down and bottom-up.

The **top-down approach** is to ask what things (tangible and intangible) are important to your system.  These things become your entities.  You then go through the process of figuring out how your entities are related to each other (your relationships) and then flesh out the entities with attributes.  The result is your conceptual or logical model.  This can be represented in ERD form if you like.

Either along the way or after your entities, relationships and attributes are defined, you go through the normalization process and make other implementation decisions to arrive at your physical model - which can also be represented as an ERD.

The **bottom-up approach** is to take your existing relations - i.e. whatever screens, reports, datastores, or whatever existing data representations you have and then perform a *canonical synthesis* to reduce the entire set of data representation into a single, coherent, normalized model.  This is done by normalizing each of your views of data and looking for commonalities that let you bring items together into a single model.

Which approach  you use depends a little bit on personal choice, and quite a bit on whether you have existing data views to start from.

Comment: Thank you. Can i ask a daft question? So i have normalised my data and of course i have more tables now than i began with, when I'm designing my er model and logical model do i act as if I've not normalised my data or is it right to include them? For example in the logical model i now have a gallery table and then a table which used the gallery primary key and the paintings on display. Which one would be correct to link to? the normalised version or not?

Comment: @JoshuaHornby There's no one right answer to your question.  You can draw an ERD at any stage.  It's just a visual representation of your model at any point in time.  As a tool, ERD makes a bit more sense with a normalized schema since that is what people expect and it doesn't have a convention for 0NF or 1NF data forms.  It really depends on what you want to show.  If your focus is the end product then draw the ERD for the normalized schema - or do the before and after if that makes sense for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should first prepare the list of entities and attributes. so that you will be able to get the complete details of the data information.

Once you are clear with the data information. You can start creating the master table and Normalize then.

Then after the complete database is design with normalization, You can create the ER diagram very easily.

Comment: you are welcome, if you flow my steps mark it as answer so that other could also follow the same steps or atleast vote up.

Comment: I can't vote up just yet and will mark as answered in a few hours just want some more ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by evaluating and then preparing the list of entites and attributes within your data.

I would do it in this order.

1. Relationships
2. Create the ER model.
3. Normalise the data.

I know many others will have a different opinion but this is the way I would go ahead with it :)